# Android Shared preferences

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I Simply want to store `String name ="Android"` using SharedPreferences from one of the Activity of my Application and latter I want to retrieve this String in BroadcastReceiver Class of same Application.

I tried everything. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below code. Make one class called PreferenceData . In that class there are two methods . One is for store the string into shared preference and another is for get the string for shared preference.

```
public class PreferenceData 
{
    static final String PREF_STORE = "store_temp";

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) 
    {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setTempString(Context ctx, String str) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_STORE, str);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getTempString(Context ctx) 
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_STORE, "");
    }
}
```

**How to Access it  ?**

```
PreferenceData.getTempString(Pass Context);   // Get Shared Preference String
PreferenceData.setTempString(Pass Context,"Android") // Set String to Shared Preference
```

Comment: Love you man ..Am on the moon now.....:D:D thanks a ton!! it workedddddd yehooo...............

Comment: It will work only for specific time if the context is removed from the memory this code with throw nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to change the string later in your code, you could put your string in hardcoded "Strigs" static variables and then only read it. It will be much easier for you to declare and read the string. If you need to read and also change the string "Android", then use this example: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.ch/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Answer (score 0):

For set a value in SharedPreferences...

```
private final String PREF = "PREF";
private final String PREF_STRING = "PREF_STRING";

final SharedPreferences preferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);        
preferences.edit().putString(PREF_STRING, "Android").commit();
```

for getting value form SharedPreferences...

```
preferences.getString(PREF_STRING, "Default value");
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to figure out if you could post the code you tired.

By the way,

```
 public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
```

this method will give you context instance. you can use that to get preferences.

```
context.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("android", "your string"); // value to store

                    editor.commit();
```

now in your Reciever class add the following

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String android= mPrefs.getString("android", null);
```

Comment: its giving this error "MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: try changing the mode if it doesn't work then try cleaning the project